# Is that ok having nested observables in mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm new to Mobx and having some troubles with it.

Is that ok having an observable inside another observable in Mobx?

I have a store:

```
class ObservableTasksStore {
  @observable
  tasks = [
    new Task(111, 'clean the car', 'with soap plz, it is really important', Duration(7, TIME.DAYS), Duration(6, TIME.MONTHS), '2018-08-17T10:02:18.674Z'),
    new Task(222, 'check car wheels', '', Duration(2, TIME.DAYS), Duration(1, TIME.MONTHS)),
    new Task(333, 'shinanint', ' check your teeth', Duration(2, TIME.DAYS), Duration(1, TIME.MONTHS))
  ]
  @action
   markTaskAsDone = (id) => {
     const index = this.tasks.findIndex((_tsk) => _tsk.id === id)
     this.tasks[index].markAsDone()
  }
```

but it doesn't call render on change.

the class to be rendered:

```
import React from 'react'
import { TaskCard } from '../TaskCard/TaskCard'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

const TasksList = ({taskStore}) => {///ObservableTasksStore passed as arg

  const tasks = taskStore.tasks

  return (
    tasks.map((task) => {

      return <TaskCard key={task.id}
                       id={task.id}
                       taskName={task.taskName}
                       description={task.description}
                       notifyDuration={task.notifyDuration}
                       recurring={task.recurring}
                       lastDone={task.lastDone}
                       daysLeft={task.daysLeft}
                       dueDate={task.dueDate}
      />
    })
  )
}

export default observer(TasksList)
```

only when I add @observable to the Task class.

1.is that Ok that `Task` also has @observable??

```
    export class Task {
      id;
      taskName;
      description;
      notifyDuration;
      recurring;
       @observable
      lastDone;
       @observable
      isActive;


 constructor (id, taskName, description, notifyDuration, recurring, lastDone, isActive) {
        this.id = id || uuidv4()
        this.taskName = taskName
        this.description = description
        this.notifyDuration = notifyDuration
        this.recurring = recurring
        this.lastDone = lastDone ? moment(lastDone) : undefined
        this.isActive = isActive || true
      }

      @action
      markAsDone () {
        this.lastDone = moment()
        this.isActive = false
      }
    }
```

the thing is that when I'm adding a mobx `strict` mode I have a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
index.module.js:768 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at initializeInstance$$1 (mobx.module.js:275)
    at ObservableTasksStore.get [as tasks] (mobx.module.js:266)
```

any idea why?

the source can be found here: 
https://github.com/yuriabaev/taskScheduler/tree/mobx-nested-observable

Comment: You shouldn't need this extra @observable annotation on your Task class. Please, provide the code for the import of the observer on the file where you declare your TaskList component.

Comment: import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

Answer (score 0):

For your case you must use `@observable` in `Task` class, because when you create an object from a class only the properties that you specify to be observables are observables (even if you push them in observable array).

To fix the issue you should enforce actions like that:

```
configure({
  enforceActions: true
});
```

from mobx version 5.1.0 you should use it like that:

```
configure({
  enforceActions: 'observed'
});
```

because you're update an observable value in the constructor, for more information: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/api.html#-enforceactions.